# Transfer people from orbiting spacecraft to surface of Mars

Tags: mars, reentry, landing, lander

What are the proposed methods for transferring people from orbiting spacecraft to Mars surface specifically if multiple trips are required. Are there any that don't require a new heat shield for each descent?

Answer (score 3):

The Shuttle didn't require a *new* heat shield each time, just refurbishment. As far as I know, SpaceX are working with Mars in mind. Their Dragon seems to be built with such reusability in mind. I haven't found much on this but [this article](http://www.spaceref.com/news/viewpr.html?pid=27612) seems to confirm this:

> All of SpaceX's initial production will be used for domestic in-house applications including the heat shields of the Dragon spacecraft, and the Falcon 9 second stage, which is designed to return from orbit for recovery and reuse.

Frankly, if there's anyone out there that does it I'd bet on SpaceX.

Comment: I've been reading a lot about plasma engines that use a magnetic containment field to keep the plasma away from the engine parts that could not withstand the heat. Would it not be feasible to have a magnetic heat shield using superconducting magnets to keep the superheated air away from the spacecraft.

Comment: @MikeTyler, that sounds like a good question -- go ahead and ask it!  Stack Exchange isn't a discussion forum; here we make a new thread for each new question.

Comment: Actually, it's already been discussed here: http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/6506/re-entry-heat-shield-alternative

Answer (score 3):

According to [this article](https://linuxacademy.com/blog/space/comparing-heat-shields-mars-science-lab-vs-spacex-dragon/), the PICA-X heat shield on SpaceX's Dragon ablates less than 15% on a single *Earth* reentry. I assume that Mars's thinner atmosphere and lower gravity (-> lower orbital speed) implies that there would be even less ablation in a Mars entry.