# What are reentry speeds of space vehicles?

Tags: reentry, atmosphere

I found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmospheric_entry) that the entry speed of meteors reach 48 km/s. I mean just before hitting atmosphere.

What are reentry speeds for space vehicles like the lunar [command module](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_Command/Service_Module#Command_Module_.28CM.29)?

What about soyuz spacecraft?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That same [Wikipedia article on Atmospheric entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmospheric_entry) that you link to in your question answers this later on:

> ... for entry from low Earth orbit where entry velocity is
>   approximately 7.8 km/s. For lunar return entry of 11 km/s ...

And also:

> The [Stardust](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stardust_%28spacecraft%29) sample-return capsule was the fastest man-made object
>   ever to reenter Earth's atmosphere (12.4 km/s or 28,000 mph at 135 km
>   altitude).

More specifically, for Soyuz reentry see [What is the maximum velocity at which Soyuz TMA-M may transit through Earth' atmosphere at reentry without a heat-shield?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/6521/49) And for Apollo missions see [Apollo by the numbers - Entry, Splashdown, and Recovery](http://history.nasa.gov/SP-4029/Apollo_18-40_Entry_Splashdown_and_Recovery.htm) (table of contents [here](http://www.history.nasa.gov/SP-4029/Apollo_00g_Table_of_Contents.htm)). Apollo 10 had the fastest maximum entry velocity at 36,397 ft/s (11.094 km/s).

Future Earth atmospheric reentry speeds might substantially increase for return missions to Mars, with entry speeds in the 15-21 km/s range, depending on trajectory and time of launch (source: [A simple atmosphere reentry guidance scheme for return from the manned Mars mission](http://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19660015097.pdf), Henry C. Lessing and Robert E. Coate, 1966, NASA Ames Research Center).

Comment: To complement - the fastest atmospheric entry by human-made object happened not on the Earth but on Jupiter. Galileo atmospheric probe entered Jupiter's atmosphere with velocity of 47.8 kilometers per second. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galileo_Probe